# R-Software: Counting occurrence combination in a column based on second column

Tags: r

I have a simple problem (seemingly) but have not yet able to find an appropriately quick/time &  resource efficient solution. This is a problem in R-Software.
My data is of format:

```
INPUT
col1     col2
A         q
C         w
B         e
A         r
A         t
A         y
C         q
B         w
C         e
C         r
B         t
C         y

DESIRED OUTPUT
unit1     unit2     same_col2_freq
A          B          1
A          C          3
B          A          1
B          C          2
C          A          3
C          B          2
```

That is in input **A** has occurred in col1 with **q, r, t, y** occurring in col2. Now, **q, r, t, y** occurs for **B** with **t** so the A-B combination has count 1.
**B** has occurred in col1 with **e, w, t** occurring in col2. Now, **e, w, t** occurs for **C** with **w, t** so the B-C combination has count 2.
.... and so on for all combinations in col1.

I have done it using a for loop but it is slow. I am picking unique elements from col1 and then, all the data is iterated for each element of col1. Then I am combining the results using rbind. This is slow and resource costly.

I am looking for an efficient method. Maybe a library, function etc. exists that I am unaware of. I tried using co-occurrence matrix but the number of elements in col1 is of order of ~10,000 and it does not solve my purpose.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar approach (as showed by @cogitovita), but using `data.table`.  Convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" using `setDT`, then Cross Join (`CJ`) the unique elements of "col1", grouped by "col2".  Subset the rows of the output columns that are not equal (`V1!=V2`), get the count (`.N`), grouped by the new columns (`.(V1, V2)`) and finally order the columns (`order(V1,V2)`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,CJ(unique(col1), unique(col1)), col2][V1!=V2, 
         .N, .(V1,V2)][order(V1,V2)]  
#   V1 V2 N
#1:  A  B 1
#2:  A  C 3
#3:  B  A 1
#4:  B  C 2
#5:  C  A 3
#6:  C  B 2
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(col1 = c("A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", 
"C", "C", "B", "C"), col2 = c("q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "q", 
"w", "e", "r", "t", "y")), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), class =
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: thanks. with my limited knowledge of R this was harder to think

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge` to join the dataframe with itself and then use `aggregate` to count within groups. demo:

```
d = data.frame(col1=c("A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "B", "C"), col2=c("q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"))
dm = merge(d, d, by="col2")
dm = dm[dm[,'col1.x']!=dm[,'col1.y'],]
aggregate(col2 ~ col1.x + col1.y, data=dm, length)
#       col1.x col1.y col2
# 1      B      A    1
# 2      C      A    3
# 3      A      B    1
# 4      C      B    2
# 5      A      C    3
# 6      B      C    2
```

Comment: works like a charm. I was actually surprised at the speed aggregate worked over the huge dataset. Thanks